# Parallelize audio playbacks in Flutter game

Tags: flutter, audio

In my Flutter game there is a grid of elements, every one of which plays a sound when being tapped (I use [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) library for that).

My issue is that when too many taps in a queue are being recognized, the whole app just freezes for a few seconds.
When I disable playing sound on tap, this problem seems to doesn't occur.

So what is the proper way to parallelize audio playbacks in such a cases?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of audioplayers library himselft answered my question.
For everyone who may face the same issue in future -- feel free to refer to this:
https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/issues/388

In short: suggested solution is to use AudioPool tool from the Flame library. Please see the link above for details.